# gives Exception in set the value of EditText

Tags: android

I am creating dynamically 2 dimentional EditText of Array. And i want to get the value of 1 EditText and set it to another EditText. It gives me Exception on setting (editText[2][2].setText(ss);) the value of EditText.

```
final EditText editText[][] = new EditText[row_size][col_size];
for(int i=0;i<row_size;i++){
  TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
  a=i;
  for(int j=0;j<col_size;j++){
    final int i_count=i;
    final int j_count=j;
    id++;
    editText[i][j] = new EditText(this);                        
    allEds.add(editText[i][j]);
    editText[i][j].setId(id);
    hold_ids.add(editText[i][j].getId());

    editText[i][j].setWidth(90);
    editText[i][j].addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {}
        @Override
          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          ss=editText[i_count][j_count].getText().toString();
          editText[2][2].setText(ss);
        }
      });
```

**Logcat error::**

```
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341): java.lang.StackOverflowError
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:261)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:150)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:4993)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5491)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2724)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2592)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2567)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at project.Excel.AndroidProjectActivity$1.afterTextChanged(AndroidProjectActivity.java:107)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6309)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2731)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2592)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2567)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at project.Excel.AndroidProjectActivity$1.afterTextChanged(AndroidProjectActivity.java:107)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6309)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2731)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2592)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2567)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at project.Excel.AndroidProjectActivity$1.afterTextChanged(AndroidProjectActivity.java:107)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6309)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2731)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2592)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2567)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at project.Excel.AndroidProjectActivity$1.afterTextChanged(AndroidProjectActivity.java:107)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6309)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2731)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2592)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2567)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at project.Excel.AndroidProjectActivity$1.afterTextChanged(AndroidProjectActivity.java:107)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6309)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2731)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2592)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2567)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at project.Excel.AndroidProjectActivity$1.afterTextChanged(AndroidProjectActivity.java:107)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6309)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2731)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2592)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2567)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at project.Excel.AndroidProjectActivity$1.afterTextChanged(AndroidProjectActivity.java:107)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6309)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2731)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2592)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2567)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at project.Excel.AndroidProjectActivity$1.afterTextChanged(AndroidProjectActivity.java:107)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6309)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2731)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2592)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2567)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at project.Excel.AndroidProjectActivity$1.afterTextChanged(AndroidProjectActivity.java:107)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6309)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2731)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2592)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2567)
03-30 17:28:27.695: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at project.Excel.AndroidProjectActivity$1.afterTextChanged(AndroidProjectActiv
03-30 17:28:31.234: I/Process(341): Sending signal. PID: 341 SIG: 9
```

Comment: @Samir pLEASE CHECK THE LOGCAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop here. The exception is a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` (see the beginning of your logcat) because when you call `editText[2][2].setText(ss)` in your `afterTextChanged()` method, that generates a callback to the `afterTextChanged()` method of the EditText view that you modified, and that calls `setText(ss)` again which generates another callback, etc, etc, ad infinitim (or until you get a StackOverflowError).

You need to either think about another way of doing this, or at least find a way to stop the infinite recursion.

Comment: yes Sir you are right, so please tell me any solution. i was trying to think about the solution but i am still confused that what will be the solution..please help me :-/

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure what you want to do. But, since you seem to be calling setText() on the view at editText[2][2], you could add something like this to your afterTextChanged() callback as the first line of code: `if (s == editText[2][2]) return; // ignore setText callback on cell at [2][2]`

Comment: i have just want to set the edittext[2][2] after get the value from edittext[i][j] in my afterTextChanged()

Comment: i did'nt understand your solution please elaborate your solution

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the scenario here. In order to give you a code solution, I need more info. Can the user edit the text in editText[2][2] himself?