# access edittext from textwatcher

Tags: java, android

I am using a textWatcher :

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
                    if(s.length() > 0) {
                    tv.setText(s.toString().substring(s.length()-1));
                    et.setText("");
                }
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int count, int after){} 
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    });
```

this return error ,I can't access the et.setText because it's final maybe or because it's locked by the Keyboard , any idea ?

Log cat :

```
06-02 13:35:25.139: D/AndroidRuntime(12532): Shutting down VM
06-02 13:35:25.139: W/dalvikvm(12532): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532): java.lang.StackOverflowError
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView$InsertionPointCursorController.hide(TextView.java:8609)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.hideInsertionPointCursorController(TextView.java:9088)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.hideControllers(TextView.java:9105)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2677)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2662)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:178)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2637)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at com.pack.witch.Input$1.beforeTextChanged(Input.java:27)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.sendBeforeTextChanged(TextView.java:6554)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2702)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2662)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:178)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2637)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at com.pack.witch.Input$1.beforeTextChanged(Input.java:27)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.sendBeforeTextChanged(TextView.java:6554)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2702)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2662)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:178)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2637)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at com.pack.witch.Input$1.beforeTextChanged(Input.java:27)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.sendBeforeTextChanged(TextView.java:6554)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2702)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2662)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:178)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2637)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at com.pack.witch.Input$1.beforeTextChanged(Input.java:27)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.sendBeforeTextChanged(TextView.java:6554)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2702)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2662)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:178)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2637)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at com.pack.witch.Input$1.beforeTextChanged(Input.java:27)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.sendBeforeTextChanged(TextView.java:6554)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2702)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2662)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:178)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2637)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at com.pack.witch.Input$1.beforeTextChanged(Input.java:27)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.sendBeforeTextChanged(TextView.java:6554)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2702)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2662)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:178)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2637)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at com.pack.witch.Input$1.beforeTextChanged(Input.java:27)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.sendBeforeTextChanged(TextView.java:6554)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2702)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2662)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:178)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2637)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at com.pack.witch.Input$1.beforeTextChanged(Input.java:27)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.sendBeforeTextChanged(TextView.java:6554)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2702)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2662)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:178)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2637)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at com.pack.witch.Input$1.beforeTextChanged(Input.java:27)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.sendBeforeTextChanged(TextView.java:6554)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2702)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2662)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:178)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2637)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at com.pack.witch.Input$1.beforeTextChanged(Input.java:27)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.sendBeforeTextChanged(TextView.java:6554)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2702)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2662)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:178)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2637)
06-02 13:35:25.219: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at com.pack.witch.Input
```

Ps : I need to change what the user types for example if he types "A" I'll show "D" it make it looks like he types "D"

Comment: final should not be problem ......can you provide log cat.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){

            }
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int count, int after){} 
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(s.length() > 0) {
                tv.setText(s.toString().substring(s.length()-1));
                et.setText("");}
         }
});
```

Comment: When I replace et.setText(""); to et.setText("anything"); I got a stackoverflow again the et must stay empty

Answer (score 2):

It's a stack overflow. The text is changing which calls text watcher which changes the text which calls your text watcher which changes the text which calls your text watcher...

You should remove your text watcher prior to changing the text within it.

Comment: But I need to change what the user types for example if he types "A" I'll show "D" it make it looks like he types "D" so I need to use a listener on the virtual keyboard which gives me the pressed character

Comment: Inside your TextWatcher remove the watcher from the EditText, immediately prior to calling setText. Immediately after calling setText re-add the TextWatcher with addTextChangedListener

Answer (score 1):

may  be [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged%28android.text.Editable%29))

This method is called to notify you that, somewhere within s, the text has been changed. It is legitimate to make further changes to s from this callback, but be careful not to get yourself into an infinite loop, because any changes you make will cause this method to be called again recursively. (You are not told where the change took place because other afterTextChanged() methods may already have made other changes and invalidated the offsets. But if you need to know here,

not the beest soulution but take look 
try this

[How to update the same EditText using TextWatcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498155/android-java-update-same-edittext-in-textchanged-event)

or

final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
boolean isManulChange = false;

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){

                if(isManulChange ){
                     isManulChange   = false;
                     return;
                   }

                if(s.length() > 0) {
                tv.setText(s.toString().substring(s.length()-1));
                et.setText("");
                isManulChange   = true;//
            }
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int count, int after){} 
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
});
```

Comment: There is no way to get out the infinite loop :/ !!

Comment: i dont observe any infinite loop? s.length() will be 1 and second time will be 0

Comment: @Agarwal : may be you are right this is my perception that as in code et is being set in afterTextChanged so it will again make a call to Text watcher and so on.... that's why he is getting the Stackoverflow exception.... even I have a bit doubt that if every time he is setting "" same text then should textchange call be generate ? but looking log cat it is some thing like that as Stackoverflow exception is there ...

Comment: @Agarwal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947287/gives-exception-in-set-the-value-of-edittext

Comment: running the callback code alternative calls........ I edited the answer Please take a look.................

Answer (score 0):

by this you can prevent infinite loop

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    if (textWatchEdited) {
        textWatchEdited = false;
        return;
    }
    String str = charSequence.toString();
    // do something
    textWatchEdited = true;
    view.setText(str);
}
```

Comment: Provided code might help, but in order to make it a good answer you should also describe/explain why/how exactly does your code solve the problem.