# How to replace (.) to (,) while entering text in Edittextview in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to replace (.) with (,) run time by entering text in edittextview in android.
i use textwatcher but it can't help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Add a TextChangedListener to the EditText with the following afterTextChanged:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    double doubleValue = 0;
    if (s != null) {
        try {
            doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(s.toString().replace(',', '.'));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //Error
        }
    }
    //Do something with doubleValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        s.toString().replace(".",",");
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing text from `afterTextChanged()` will cause an infinite loop as it will trigger itself.
So, you have two options:

-the first is to disable the text change listener, change the text and then re enable it, as per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862657/edittext-change-text-while-typing)

-the second is to check if the text needs changing before actually changing it, so it will only be called the first time it is changed.